# 80 tabards in 80 dungeons at level 85/90

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I know you can't go to an 85 or 90 dungeon and expect to get an 80 rep in there, even with a tabard.

But if I do an 80 dungeon, and I'm wearing an 80 tabard, will I get the appropriate rep?

I've tried Google-fu, but am coming up blank. I know I could just try it, but it would probably take a while to make it there.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the full amount of Reputation from all the dungeons that are level 80. You will just need to get the tabards that you want for exalted.

Here is the Argent Crusade Tabard as an example:

http://www.wowhead.com/item=43154

Also:

For the Record, every mob in heroic mode grants rep towards the Alliance Vanguard/Horde Expedition. Wearing the Wyrmrest Accord, Kirin Tor, The Ebon Blade or Argent Crusade Tabards CONVERTS that rep to the faction whose tabard you're wearing.

List of dungeons that give rep:

- Utgarde Pinnacle (norm)
- Culling for Startholme (norm)
- Occulus (norm)
- Halls of Lightning (norm)
- All Northrend Heroics

Per comment from Wowhead